# How to toggle classes on a single div?

Tags: jquery, html

Noob question here: I have the following html code, how to toggle between `.active` and `.inactive` in jQuery for only one placeholder while hovering.

For example: if I hover over the first div both of them become active, I want to have `.active` only over the one I'm hovering. I know It's kind of spaghetti code but I'm a little stuck, hope you understood what I wanted to say.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inactive">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder  ">
            <a href="http://codepen.io/gabew3/full/YpKGwr/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/A92WrwJ.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <p class="text-center">A tribute page dedicated to Agatha Christie</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inactive">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder ">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5P1UTjv.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <p class="text-center">Placeholder</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why just not use `:hover` in css and define your properties in this ? (`.wrapper>div:hover{...}`)

Comment: Also, no need to use two classes. Just style the regular div, and then add the .active-class when you want (removing it on mouseout, for instance)

Comment: As Alexis stated use `hover` class you can refer the sample on this link `http://jsfiddle.net/7v7ys/2/`

Comment: What is it you want to do to the div whilst it is hovered over? By that what I'd like to understand is that if you want to change the inactive to active for styling purposes only whilst it is hovered, it might be easier to do it using CSS rather than javascript. Eg, .inactive:hover{color:red}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method alongwith [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```
$('.wrapper').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

***Note:*** Please note that one `div` in your structure is excess. You can have `active` and `inactive` classes on `div.wrapper`.

```js
$('.wrapper').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wrapper inactive">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder  ">
    <a href="http://codepen.io/gabew3/full/YpKGwr/">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/A92WrwJ.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <p class="text-center">A tribute page dedicated to Agatha Christie</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper inactive">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5P1UTjv.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <p class="text-center">Placeholder</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods.

When you hover `.wrapper` it switch between `.active` and `.inactive`. I added some css to those classes to see the difference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  
  $wrapper.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       $wrapper.addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    }, mouseleave: function() {
       $wrapper.addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper.inactive {
 opacity: 0.5;
}

.wrapper.active {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inactive">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder  ">
      <a href="http://codepen.io/gabew3/full/YpKGwr/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/A92WrwJ.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p class="text-center">A tribute page dedicated to Agatha Christie</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inactive">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 placeholder ">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5P1UTjv.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p class="text-center">Placeholder</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need any further explanation about the js code, let me know.